# iPhone BLE: How could I get the status of call and short message background?

Tags: iphone, ios, background

I'd like to be notified when a call or short message is coming to iPhone,and then I will send something via BLE to remote device so that the remote device can do some actions immediately,such as alert or vibrate.

Here I have two questions about this application context about iPhone:

1. How does the BLE App run background in IPhone to monitor the incoming call or short message? What should I do next after adding "bluetooth-central" into  p-list?
2. How should I get the status of incoming call or message?

What should I do to get this status for a jailbreak iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

You'll will need to use classic bluetooth to support what is known as bluetooth MAP, which will give you access to receive notifications from your iPhone of any sms and calls received and pushed to your bluetooth MAP-supported device. I do not think this is supported via BLE.

[Bluetooth MAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Message_Access_Profile_.28MAP.29) stands for Message Access Protocol.